# Terminology: Forward Declaration versus Function Prototype

Tags: c, terminology, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

To me these terms are essentially synonymous when using the C programming language.  In practice I might prefer "forward declaration" for in-file prototypes versus "function prototype" for prototypes included via a header file.  But even that is an artificial distinction when you consider what happens after preprocessing.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Is there a consensus for when to use one term versus the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO those are not really synonyms.
To me "function prototype" refer to the function name and its parameters' and return's types. It does not only apply to what you call "forward declaration". All functions have a prototype.

We more often make a difference between a function **declaration** and its corresponding **definition**.

Comment: +1, although it's really common to use the word "prototype" to refer to the declaration.

Comment: I think you and @MatteoItalia have summed it up.  I've been using the term prototype when I should be using the term declaration.

Answer (score 10):

The term "prototype" refers to a specific declaration syntax; specifically, that the number and types of parameters to the function appear in the declaration.  Given a function *definition* of

```
int foo(int a, char *b) {...}
```

you can have any of the following *declarations*:

```
int foo();                // a declaration, but not a prototype
int foo(a, b);            // a declaration, but not a prototype
int foo(int, char *);     // a declaration and a prototype
int foo(int a, char *b);  // a declaration and a prototype
```

Comment: Your option `int foo(a, b);` is only valid if `a` and `b` are known type names, or if it is followed by the function body `{ … }` instead of a semicolon.

Answer (score 7):

I use the term forward declaration for the following kind of `struct` declaration with a definition.

```
struct Foo;
```

A function declaration need not be a full prototype, for compatibility with pre-1989 (K&R) C.

```
char *foo();  // NOT the same as char *foo(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only concept in C I'm aware of is the distinction between declaration and definition. A prototype is a declaration and can happen anywhere, anytime and the definition which is the actual implementation od the given object. by that concept, there is no thing called forward declaration, ther's only an order of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a consensus, but I think the cleanest way to do it would be:

- Place all declarations in header files, never in source or .c files. (I think you mean declaration when you say forward declaration.)
- Place all definitions in source files

I don't like to place declarations in files because you can have conflicting declarations without errors in C, which can cause segfaults, for example: if a.c has

```
int foo(char *str_one, char *str_two, char *str_three);
```

and b.c has

```
int foo(char *str_one, char *str_two);
```

you will not get warnings nor errors, and calls made to foo() from b.c will not place all the parameters on the stack where they should be, meaning foo() will just grab something from the stack and treat it as str_three, possibly leading to a segfault. So for me, declarations go to header files and definitions go to source files.

Comment: Declarations for `static` functions should be put in the C file they are defined in imho, preferably at the beginning.

Comment: @tristopia - good point, I wasn't thinking about static functions when I got on my soapbox there. I definitely wouldn't declare those in a header file.