# Can someone explain this function prototype and how it corrrelates to the if statement

Tags: c, function, if-statement

```
static int exists (int x, int A[], int n);

void read(int A[], int *nA)
{
    *nA=0;
    char c;
    int x;
    do {
        scanf("%d%c",&x,&c);
        if (!exists(x,A,*nA))
        {
            A[*nA]=x;
            (*nA)++;
        }
    } while (c==',');
}
```

So I can't understand how the function prototype `exists` works. I mean, it's theoretically a function, but what exactly does it do? And the if statement `if(!exists(x,A,*nA)` does what exactly? I found that the ! type of if statements are equivalent to `exists(x,A,nA)==0`, but I dont know how to interpret this in a C context.

Comment: The `read` function is filling an array with **unique** numbers. It calls the `exists` function to make sure that the value in `x` isn't already in the array. If `x` doesn't exist in the array, then it's added to the array.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. Thank you!

Comment: If my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in my answer, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand how the function prototype exists works. I mean, it's theoretically a function, but what exactly does it do?

It's just a **declaration**, to tell the compiler that it can expect a **definition** of this function later on and it shouldn't throw an error when it comes accross a call to this not yet defined function.
[related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496284/terminology-forward-declaration-versus-function-prototype)

> I found that the ! type of if statements are equivalent to exists(x,A,nA)==0,

That's correct.

> but I dont know how to interpret this in a C context.

The `exists` function returns an `int`, probably 0 and 1 for false and true.
The `!`operator means `not` ([logical negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)) and is here applied to the return value of the function. If the function returns 0, which is considered as false, you have a logical *not false*. So you can read it as

```
if not exists
```

So the body of the `if` statement will be executed if something doesn't exist yet.